# IntelliJ IDEA: Include external library in production directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Java project. To include the mysql-connector-java library I use, I created a folder named lib in the root of the project and added the JAR to it. After that I added it as a global library using the context menu.
When debugging it, everything is working fine. But when I navigate to the production directory and try to run it from the command line it cannot find the library. How can I include it in the production directory to allow accessing it when running my main class? Or is there another way to get this done? I just want to make sure, that all external libraries my project is depending on are properly included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the command line you should use -cp to add jars or directories to classpath (as explaind [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#tooloption) ). if you want to run with intellij Idea then you create a run configuration (which I thing you've already done) and then in the configuration select you module in option **use class path of module** part of the configuration.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to automatically include all the JAR files in the build directory. I thought that way I don't have to fiddle around with classpath and have one single directory to give to classmates. But it seems that this is not how it is done.

Comment: generally you should use build tools for this purpose. [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the library/jar to your BuildPath.

Just take a look at the ["Correct way to add a library to an IntelliJ project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)